# Laravel: Using policy on FormRequest always returns false

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to authorize whether a user is allowed to invite other users.

InvitedUserController

```
public function store(InvitedUserRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
        $data['account_id'] = $request->session()->get('account_id');
        InvitedUser::create($data);
    }
```

I created a FormRequest class to handle validation:

```
class InvitedUser extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(Request $request)
    {
        $account = Account::find($request->session()->get('account_id'));
        return $this->user()->can('manageUsers', $account);
    }

    /**
     * Validation error message
     */
    public function messages() {
        return [
            'max' => 'You may only enter up to :max characters'
        ];
    }

    public function invalid() {

    }
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|max:255|email',
            'role_id' => 'required|exists:roles,id',
        ];
    }
}
```

Then my policy to handle authorization:

```
class InvitedUserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function manageUsers(User $user, Account $account)
    {   
        dd('test');
        $role = $user->roles()->wherePivot('account_id', $account->id)->first();
        return $role->manage_users;
    }

}
```

I registered the policy:

```
protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        'App\InvitedUser' => 'App\Policies\InvitedUserPolicy'
    ];
```

For some reason, that `dd()` call doesn't even occur. So it's not reaching my policy and all requests are returning unauthorized.

even if i changed my policy to return true

```
public function manageUsers(User $user, Account $account)
    {   
        return true;
    }
```

I would still get unauthorized

How Can I call my policy from a FormRequest? Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

So, while this is confusing to me, I've figured out the issue.

I needed to change my registered policies to the following:

```
protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        'App\Account' => 'App\Policies\InvitedUserPolicy'
    ];
```

It's using the Account model instead of InvitedUser model. I think because that's what I'm passing in as a model?